# react-native-firebase-mlkit textRecognizerProcessImage is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, firebase-mlkit

After installing react native-firebase core app and mlkit. mlkit does not work and fails when I try to use the function textRecognizerProcessImage.

I followed: https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/v6/ml-vision/quick-start and additionally for ios I did an pod install and saw how mlkit was downloaded. 
However, the error from above occurs on android and ios. 
Does anybody have a clue?

EDIT: I am also having access to the firebase-project using `google-services.json`and `googleservice-info.plist`

the relevant part from my package.json. Am using newest versions for all.
(As you can see I am also using /auth and /database both of which work just fine!

```js
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/database": "^6.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/ml-vision": "^6.0.0",
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.61.1"
  },
```

the firebase.json:

```js
{
  "react-native": {
    "ml_vision_face_model": true,
    "ml_vision_ocr_model": true,
    "ml_vision_barcode_model": true,

    "ml_vision_label_model": true,
    "ml_vision_image_label_model": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple solution...
The documentation talks about

`import vision from '@react-native-firebase/ml-vision';`

to import the vision library. However,
vision.anyFunctionHere will not work, since it is no instance.

the solution is to use `vision().anyFunctionHere`  (not the brackets of doom which cost me hours and a hell lot of frustration-.-)

Comment: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/2650#issuecomment-536492576 for more info